# How to show which layers are currently visible

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to show which layers are visible from a dynamic layer. I see all the objects being returned in the console with a 'visible' property. For some reason, I can't access that property.

My code:

```
var baseData = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://arcserver/arcgis/rest/services/Base_Data/Resources_All/MapServer", {
    opacity : 0.8
});

function buildLayerList() {
    var visible = [];       
    var items = array.map(baseData.layerInfos, function(info, index) {
                console.dir(info);
        if (info.visible === true) {
          visible.push("<li>" + info.name + "</li>");
        }
      });
      var ll = dom.byId("selectedBaselayers");
      ll.innerHTML = visible.join(' ');
    }
```

I want to access this property:

[image]

Comment: The 'baseData' service is on our local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample shows how to get visibility of layer from a dynamic layer

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_dynamic_reorder.html

In your case the code would be

```
var dynamicLayerInfos = baseData.createDynamicLayerInfosFromLayerInfos();
var visible = [];

arrayUtils.forEach(dynamicLayerInfos, function(info) {

      if (arrayUtils.indexOf(baseData.visibleLayers, info.id) > -1) {
        visible.push("<li>" + info.name + "</li>");
      }

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that your service is hosted on a local network, I am editing my answer accordingly.

After your service has loaded you could use the following in the console, which would log all of the visible layers:

```
var vislyrs = baseData.visibleLayers;

for (i=0;i<vislyrs.length;i++){
    console.log("Index " + vislyrs[i] + " is visible (" + baseData.layerInfos[i].name +")")
}
```

For [this](http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Demographics/USA_1990-2000_Population_Change/MapServer) service it would for example log the following:

[image]

Comment: forgot to mention that the service is on our local network

Comment: OK, thought it was an Esri sample server!

Comment: Wait! You forgot to add the layer to the map! map.addLayer(baseData);

Comment: this is just a snip of my code, the baseData has been added to the map. I just want to check to see if my array is setup correctly.

Comment: I added a screenshot from the console output, You can hopefully see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: *baseData.visibleLayers* returns an array which contains the indexes of the layers that are visible. Could you use that as a workaround? You could call that one first and then loop through the indexes in the array, using: *baseData.layerInfos[index].name*, which would then returns the names of all the layers that are visible.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0L34do59/

Comment: I updayed this fiddle to show you what Im trying to accomplish.  http://jsfiddle.net/ishiland/0L34do59/1/

Comment: Thank you. I am not next to my computer anymore but I will have a look at it tomorrow! PS: I have updated my answer in case you missed that.

Comment: yes thanks for the help, I took a look at it and I have not been able to get it to work

Comment: In the console or in the script? If used in the script it might be fired before the service has completely loaded and therefore will not work. Strangely enough The API seems to be missing any callbacks or 'loaded' events for dynamic layers.

Comment: thanks, got it to work:  http://jsfiddle.net/ishiland/0L34do59/3/

Comment: one issue though - its only returning the group name of the layer, not the actually layer name itself

Comment: Glad it works. You might have to dig in deeper. Wasn't aware of that, but I will have a look at it tomorrow and fiddle with it some more!